# Ускорить парсинг большого файла

Tags: javascript, node.js, парсер

Я только начал изучать NodeJS и наконец смог вывести окно с интерфейсом, а так же сделать выбор файла..
Цель была: При выборе файла пройтись по всем строкам и сделать с ними действия (соответствует регулярному выражению и т.д.) так же нужно было убрать дубли данных из строки (то есть, если уже была строка с такими данными - мы ее пропускаем).
Я сделал массив и добавлял в него эти данные, а при новой строке я проверял через indexOf.
В файле который нужно парсить больше 1.000.000 строк, занимает это очень много времени и мне необходимо как-то это ускорить. Я подозреваю, что узкое место - тот самый массив.

Для записи в новый файл строк, который прошли проверки я использую ( stream = fs.createWriteStream ) и внутри ( stream.write(...) ).

Из найденого в гугле способа чтения большого файла я остановился на этом:

```
fs.createReadStream(path.format(filePath))
    .pipe(es.split())
    .pipe(es.mapSync(line => { ... })
```

Цель: найти способ, который ускорит весь процесс.

```
const { ipcRenderer: ipc, remote: app } = require('electron');
const path                              = require('path');
const es                                = require('event-stream');
const fs                                = require('fs');


const selectFileBtn = document.querySelector('.selectFile__btn');
      selectFileBtn.addEventListener('click', selectFile, false);
const parsingDeleted = document.querySelector('.parsing__deleted');
const parsingStatus  = document.querySelector('.parsing__status');
const parsingDouble  = document.querySelector('.parsing__double');
const parsingFile    = document.querySelector('.parsing__file');


function selectFile()
{
    app.dialog.showOpenDialog(
        {
            properties : ["openFile"],
            title      : 'Выбери файл для парсинга',
            buttonLabel: 'Выбрать',
            filters    :
            [
                {name: 'Text file', extensions: ['txt']},
            ]
        }
    )
        .then(data => data.filePaths)
        .then(files =>
            {
                if (!files.length)
                {
                    return;
                }

                let data          = new Map();
                let count         = 0, count_double = 0;
                let time          = new Date().getTime();
                let filePath      = path.parse(files[0].split(String.fromCharCode(92)).join(String.fromCharCode(92,92)));
                let fileSavedPath = `${filePath.dir}\\${filePath.name}__parsed${filePath.ext}`;

                parsingFile.innerText = filePath.base;

                parsingDeleted.innerText = count;
                parsingDoble.innerText = count_double;

                parsingStatus.innerText = `Обработка файла...`;

                document.querySelector('.selectFile').style.display = 'none';
                document.querySelector('.parsing').style.display = 'block';


                let stream = fs.createWriteStream(fileSavedPath);
                stream.once('open', fd =>
                {
                    fs.createReadStream(path.format(filePath))
                    .pipe(es.split())
                    .pipe(es.mapSync(line =>
                        {
                            line = line.replace(/^\+/, '').replace(/;/g, ':');

                            if (!line || /[А-Яа-я]/.test(line) || !/[7-9]/.test(line.substr(0, 1)))
                            {
                                count++;
                                parsingDeleted.innerText = count;
                                return;
                            }


                            if (line.substr(0, 1) == 9)
                            {
                                line = '7' +line;
                            }
                            else if (line.substr(0, 1) == 8)
                            {
                                line = '7' +line.substr(1);
                            }

                            if (data.has(line.split(':')[1]))
                            {
                                count_double++;
                                parsingDouble.innerText = count_double;
                                return;
                            }

                            data.set(line.split(':')[1], 1);
                            stream.write(`${line}\n`);
                        })
                        .on('error', err =>
                        {
                            console.log('Ошибка', err);
                        })
                        .on('end', function()
                        {
                            stream.end();
                            parsingStatus.innerText = `Завершено`;
                            console.log(`Усее, прошло времени: ${new Date().getTime() - time}`);
                            console.log(`Удалено строк: ${count}`);
                            console.log(`Удалено дублей: ${count_double}`);
                        })
                    );
                });
            }
        );
}
```

Comment: Можете из ноды вызвать какую-нибудь консольную утилиту для удаления дублей строк, которая может быть оптимизирована для таких дел, и потом уже загружать файл. Тогда массивы не потребуются.

Comment: Там строка допустим формата *****:*****:***** и нужно чтобы по середине оно проверяло, были ли данные такие или нет.

Comment: Без кода сложно судить что вызывает задержки. И вы можете через замеры времени или через отладку на временной линии узнать какая именно часть вызывает наибольшие задержки.

Comment: "через отладку на временной линии узнать какая именно часть вызывает наибольшие задержки"
Можно подробнее? Как эту временную линию "вызвать"?

Comment: Ищите в гугле или на ютубе как делать отладку ноды в хроме. В консоли хрома можно записать сколько времени тратит каждая функция, в виде удобного графика. Вот ссылка на док, но тут мало что понятно - https://nodejs.org/ru/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/#chrome-55-microsoft-edge

Comment: Добавил код в первый пост.

Comment: Пробуйте удалить поиск элементов и запись в них текста. Общение с DOM столько раз - это накладные операции.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что общение с DOM довольно накладно и наверное нужно было вынести в переменные, но хочется видеть результат в "real time", и так не стал делать пройденное кол-во строк.

Comment: А вы говорите что видите как числа обновляются в реалтайме на сколько я понял. На что тогда завязана одна итерация такого разбора? На таймер какой-то?

Comment: Не совсем понял о чем вы.
Я тут убрал проверку на "дубли" и все пропарсило за 70с.

Comment: Я о том, что если вы в рантайме видите какие-то обновления чисел, значит у вас возможны отрисовки браузера, значит 60 итераций в секунду всего.

Comment: У меня интерфейс на электроне.
Я использовал еще предложение ниже с Map, оно увеличило время парсинга с 70с до 115с. Не значительно, я бы даже сказал идеально, можно ли еще что-то с этим сделать?

Comment: Думаю так удалённо сложно будет что-то улучшать, не видя как это работает всё и весь код. Так что если хотите чтобы тут ещё отвечали, можете больше кода написать, или опубликовать программу куда-то. Иначе будет пальцем в небо.

Comment: Отредактировал пост, в нем все содержимое .js файла.

Comment: можете куда-нибудь выложить файл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Я сделал массив и добавлял в него эти данные, а при новой строке я
> проверял через indexOf.

Используйте [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). Поскольку эта структура намного быстрее ищет элемент.

```
const myMap = new Map();

const keyObj = {},
    keyFunc = function () {},
    keyString = 'a string';

// задание значений
myMap.set(keyString, 'value associated with “a string”');
myMap.set(keyObj, 'value associated with keyObj');
myMap.set(keyFunc, 'value associated with keyFunc');

myMap.size; // 3

// получение значений
myMap.get(keyString);    // value associated with “a string”
myMap.get(keyObj);       // value associated with keyObj
myMap.get(keyFunc);      // v
```

Comment: Отличное предложение, раньше я ждал больше 40 минут и оно не дошло до финала. Я убрал проверку на дубли и все пропарсило за 70с, когда использовал данный метод с Map, время увеличилось до 115с, но по сравнению с первоначальным это небо и земля!)
Что еще можно сделать? Это уже не критично.