# Быстрый поиск одинаковых строк в двух txt на совпадение

Tags: python, c++, linux, node.js

Есть два больших txt-файла. Нужно сравнить строки из первого файла со строками из второго на совпадение. Одинаковые строки записать в новый txt-файл.
Мне известен один способ (findstr /g:1.txt 2.txt 1>result.txt) но это очень долго.

Comment: Похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1234895/%d0%a3%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0?rq=1

Comment: тот ответ имеет смысл для большого набора данных только с ответами на следующий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1236585/2659